# How Can i pass Video Path to Another Activvity using Intent?

Tags: android

Am Building an App which i want to customize my own Video Player within the App, I do not want to use default Android Media Player.
Activity 1:

```
 String VideoUri= fileUri.toString();
//            Intent videoIntent = new Intent(getListView().getContext(), VideoPlayerActivity.class);
//           videoIntent.putExtra("VideoPath", VideoUri);
//               startActivity(videoIntent);
```

**Activity 2:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog myDialog;
    VideoView myvideoview;


    final String VideoUrl=getIntent().getExtras().getString("VideoPath");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);

        myvideoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.uservideoView);


        myDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoPlayerActivity.this);

        myDialog.setTitle("Video Loading");

        myDialog.setMessage("Streaming...");
        myDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       myDialog.setCancelable(false);

        myDialog.show();

        try {

            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoPlayerActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(myvideoview);

            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoUrl);
            myvideoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            myvideoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                myDialog.dismiss();
                myvideoview.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Image Viewer works for me using Picasso API.  Is there any other way to Pass Video Uri Pass to a new Activity/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Application Singleton Like this:
http://pastebin.com/JPRvAiv7

Comment: Any guide for Pastebin ?

Comment: Paste bin is a code sharing system. What you want to know?